# Get posts with Taxonomy term meta

Tags: taxonomy, post-meta

I want to display posts by categories. In my categories, I just want to display the posts that have the term meta between 100 and 200.

How can I do that properly?

Comment: tried to make a query for this, with an array to get the meta, but no success

Comment: Maybe [Query based on Custom Field and Category](https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query#Query_based_on_Custom_Field_and_Category) helps?

Answer (score 0):

This seems a little inconvenient since there are two hops from posts to terms to term meta. `WP_Query` cannot operate with term meta since it doesn't *directly* apply to posts.

Without knowing more context of your situation and term counts involved I would guess:

1. Pre-calculate and cache the list of valid terms (those that fall into desired range of term meta value).
2. Use `pre_get_posts` to modify term archive query by limiting posts returned to having valid term assigned with taxonomy query.